# How the getRed() works properly in UIColor object in iOS 9 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

Any suggestions how this code works in iOS 9 with xcode 7?

`color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)`

It says "Expected declaration"

Here is the code:

```
var red: CGFloat = 0.0
var green: CGFloat = 0.0
var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
var alpha: CGFloat = 0.0

color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
webLabel.text = String(format: "#%02X%02%02X", CInt(red*255),CInt(green*255),CInt(blue*255))
```

"color" is assigned previously like so:

```
var color: UIColor
{
    return UIColor(hue: CGFloat(hue/360), saturation: CGFloat(saturation/100), brightness: CGFloat(brightness/100), alpha: 1.0)
}
```

I have just started with the xcode 7 and swift so I am rookie at this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28645384/2798777

Comment: Thank you, it works now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [howto get the RGB Code (INT) from an UIColor in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644311/howto-get-the-rgb-code-int-from-an-uicolor-in-swift)

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 2.0   total solution**

below is the total solution/Anwser for your question.Please be kind enough to make this answer as correct if it works.

```
func converUIColorToHex(colorToConver:UIColor)-> String{

    var red:CGFloat = 0
    var green:CGFloat = 0
    var blue:CGFloat = 0
    var alpha:CGFloat = 0

    colorToConver.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

    print(red)

    if(red < 0) {red = 0}

    if(green < 0) {green = 0}

    if(blue < 0) {blue = 0}

    if(red > 255) {red = 255}

    if(green > 255) {green = 255}

    if(blue > 255) {blue = 255}

    print(red)

    let decimalCode = Int((red * 65536) + (green * 256) + blue)

    let hexColorCode = String(decimalCode, radix: 16)

    print(hexColorCode)

    return hexColorCode
}
```