# How to convert value of type UIColor to Uint in swift

Tags: swift, colors, uicolor, uint

I got this UIColor :

```
UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.4118, blue: 0.1176, alpha: 1.0)
```

And I need to convert in Uint. How can I do that?

EDIT :

```
func showEmailMessage(advice : String)
{
    _ = SCLAlertView().showSuccess("Congratulation", subTitle: advice, closeButtonTitle: "Ok", duration : 10, colorStyle: 0x33691e, colorTextButton: 0xFFFFFF)
}
```

Color style field want Uint

Comment: How is a `UInt` supposed to represent a color?  What result are you expecting and how will this `UInt` be used?

Comment: for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300091/how-the-getred-works-properly-in-uicolor-object-in-ios-9-swift

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the `UIColor.getRed(...)` method to extract the colors as `CGFloat`, thereafter convert the values of your `CGFloat` triplet to the proper bit positions of an `UInt32` variable.

```
// Example: use color triplet CC6699 "=" {204, 102, 153} (RGB triplet)
let color = UIColor(red: 204.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 153.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

// read colors to CGFloats and convert and position to proper bit positions in UInt32
var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
if color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha) {

    var colorAsUInt : UInt32 = 0

    colorAsUInt += UInt32(red * 255.0) << 16 + 
                   UInt32(green * 255.0) << 8 + 
                   UInt32(blue * 255.0)

    colorAsUInt == 0xCC6699 // true
}
```

For details, see e.g. the [Language Guide - Advanced Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) which contains, among other valuable things, an example specifically for bit shifting w.r.t RGB triplets.

Comment: Perfect! it worked ! I just have to return UInt instead of UInt 32 ! thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarcoCastano Happy to help. The above is naturally directly applicable using `UInt` (which is, for new devices, same size as `UInt64`) instead of `UInt32`, you'll just have additional non-used bit padding.