# Is it possible to get color name in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get color name from UIButton in swift instead of value is there any way to do that. Thanks

I am using tintColor to set value as well to get value

```
    clickButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue

    var color = clickButton.tintColor
```

when I am printing color value I get (UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1) is there anyway I can get blue instead of value

Comment: Nope, you can't get the name of UIColor, the RGB values can be get. And there is no use of color name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get the "human-readable" name of a `UIColor` by using a built-in. However you can get the `RGB` values, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644311/how-to-get-the-rgb-code-int-from-an-uicolor-in-swift).

If you really want to get the name of the color, you can build your own dictionary, as @BoilingFire pointed out in their answer:

```
var color = clickButton.tintColor!     // it is set to UIColor.blue
var colors = [UIColor.red:"red", UIColor.blue:"blue", UIColor.black:"black"]  // you should add more colors here, as many as you want to support.
var colorString = String()

if colors.keys.contains(color){
    colorString = colors[color]!
}

print(colorString)     // prints "blue"
```

Comment: Nice answer, this will help you out.

Comment: Great answer. The if statement can be improved to be more Swifty, to avoid the force unwrap and to be more efficient: `if let colorName = colors[color] { colorString = colorName }`

Answer (score 13):

Add this extension to your project

```
extension UIColor {
    var name: String? {
        switch self {
        case UIColor.black: return "black"
        case UIColor.darkGray: return "darkGray"
        case UIColor.lightGray: return "lightGray"
        case UIColor.white: return "white"
        case UIColor.gray: return "gray"
        case UIColor.red: return "red"
        case UIColor.green: return "green"
        case UIColor.blue: return "blue"
        case UIColor.cyan: return "cyan"
        case UIColor.yellow: return "yellow"
        case UIColor.magenta: return "magenta"
        case UIColor.orange: return "orange"
        case UIColor.purple: return "purple"
        case UIColor.brown: return "brown"
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can write

```
print(UIColor.red.name) // Optional("red")
```

Answer (score 6):

From iOS 14.0+ you can also use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3600314-accessibilityname

```
UIColor.systemRed.accessibilityName // returns "Red"
```

Comment: For SwiftUI Color-View to an color string name: UIColor(Color.orange).accessibilityName

Answer (score 5):

You can use this extension to get name of color created via Color Assets in XCode.

```
extension UIColor {
    /// Name of color. Only colors created with XCode Color Assets will return actual name, colors created programatically will always return nil.
    var name: String? {
        let str = String(describing: self).dropLast()
        guard let nameRange = str.range(of: "name = ") else {
            return nil
        }
        let cropped = str[nameRange.upperBound ..< str.endIndex]
        if cropped.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        return String(cropped)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5 and above iOS14**

**Create an extension for UIColor**

```
extension UIColor {

convenience init(_ r: Double,_ g: Double,_ b: Double,_ a: Double) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat(r/255), green: CGFloat(g/255), blue: CGFloat(b/255), alpha: CGFloat(a))
}

convenience init(hex: String) {
    let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
    scanner.scanLocation = 0
    
    var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0
    
    scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
    
    let r = (rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
    let g = (rgbValue & 0xff00) >> 8
    let b = rgbValue & 0xff
    
    self.init(
        red: CGFloat(r) / 0xff,
        green: CGFloat(g) / 0xff,
        blue: CGFloat(b) / 0xff, alpha: 1
    )
}

func getRGBAComponents() -> (red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, alpha: Int)?
{
    var fRed : CGFloat = 0
    var fGreen : CGFloat = 0
    var fBlue : CGFloat = 0
    var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0
    if self.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha) {
        let iRed = Int(fRed * 255.0)
        let iGreen = Int(fGreen * 255.0)
        let iBlue = Int(fBlue * 255.0)
        let iAlpha = 1
        
        return (red:iRed, green:iGreen, blue:iBlue, alpha:iAlpha)
    } else {
        // Could not extract RGBA components:
        return nil
    }
}

class func colorWithRGB(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: r/255.0, green: g/255.0, blue: b/255.0, alpha: alpha)
}

convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
       assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
       assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
       assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

       self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
   }

   convenience init(rgb: Int) {
       self.init(
           red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
           green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
           blue: rgb & 0xFF
       )
   }
```

}

**Use like below Code**

```
     let RGBArray =  YOUR_RGB_COLOR?.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let _color = UIColor(red:Int(RGBArray?[0] ?? "0") ?? 255 , green: Int(RGBArray?[1] ?? "0") ?? 255, blue: Int(RGBArray?[2] ?? "0") ?? 255)
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let mString  = _color.accessibilityName
            print(mString)
        }
```

OUTPUT:

**Red**

Answer (score 2):

An extencion for class **Color** in **SwiftUI** can be :

```
extension Color {
    var name: String? {
        let description = self.description
        let firstOccurenceIndex = description.firstIndex(of: "\"") ?? description.startIndex
        let startIndex = description.index(firstOccurenceIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        let suffix = description.suffix(from: startIndex)
        let lastOccurenceIndex = suffix.firstIndex(of: "\"") ?? description.endIndex
        let name = suffix.prefix(upTo: lastOccurenceIndex)
        return String(name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible but you could build your own dictionnary and search for the key that corresponds to that color object.
Not any color would have a name anyways.

```
var colors = ["blue": UIColor.blue, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.5**

Let's assume you have a variable Orange of type UIColor.

```
var orange: UIColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 1, green: 0.5, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

You can get the color name by:

```
var colorName: String {
    orange.accessibilityName
}
```

Hope this helped. Cheers

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67683365/2227743).